# How to get table row of a website that updates dynamically (simple html DOM parser)?

Tags: php, simple-html-dom, scraper

Basically what I want to do is get a particular table row of a website. the table has an id of *"table-data"*. I have already written the PHP but I noticed that the *file_get_html* doesn't actually get the data that is dynamically loaded. How should I approach?

```
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');

$html = file_get_html('http://www.2gheroon.ir');
$es = $html->find('table.data-table');

for ($i=0 ; $i<count($es); $i++) {
    echo $es[$i]->plaintext;
}

echo $html;
```

Comment: If it's dynamically loaded you can either try to find the json, or you can use something like selenium/nightmarejs

Comment: Your URL is not valid ... we can't see what you want to scrap ! No way to scrap dynamic content with simplehtmldom. Good luck to find the json.
The proper way to fetch element + id : $ret = $html->find('div[id=foo]');
https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/manual.htm